# I don't understand the usage of the TFS branching tool

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch, git-flow

I'm evaluating tools that helps to manage branch for my team. We are working on a commercial product, so the tools must be chosen carefully to handle multiple releases, potential hotfix on older versions, etc.

Basically, what I want is to reach what **[git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)** allows.

But because we are already using TFS (2012 today, but 2013 upgrade in the pipe) with Visual Studio 2012 (but we didn't use branches before), I'd like to "stick" to a full MS product line.

Then I was looking for guidance, and I found this software. I've seen the short webcast [Quick tour of the TFS Branch Tool VS Extension](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Quick-tour-of-the-TFS-Branch-Tool-VS-Extension) on channel9 that demonstrate the tool. But it only covers the creation of the initial structure. What about day to day work?

Let's say I've finished working on a feature or a hotfix. How can I guide the developer to merge to the correct branch? How can I have a easy to read view of the work?

The tools said "automate branching task in the ALM Rangers branching guidance"... but I don't see any menu that can do that. The only thing I see is the "Create initial structure" menu.

Did I miss something? Is there any other resource that can help me?

I like GIT... I believe in its strong branching features. But I feel the git experience in VS 2012 is terrible... so I'd like to give a chance to TFS.

As my team (including me) is not mature in managing branching, I must keep things as easy as possible, so any advise is welcome.

Comment: Did you end up finding any useful tools? My team is also beginning to take branches seriously just now, so I am interested in helping it go as smooth as possible.

Comment: @SAnder: we are still investigating different ways. My feeling is that TFS protocol is not very good at branching. It's ok to have a DEV and a MAIN branch, but when you plan a complex branch strategy, it's a pain. My current target is to upgrade to TFS 2013, and create GIT repos. We will still use VS tools, but with the Microsoft Git tools for Visual Studio. I will also use SourceTree as a complementary tool, because it provides a GUI over gitflow. This looks like promising, but as I said, it's still under investigations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TFS 2013 you have the choice of 2 types of source control repositories: traditional TFS (TFVC) or Git.  You can use a fully-featured Git repository hosted in TFS that gives you all the other goodness that comes with TFS.  You can use any git client tools that you prefer to connect and work with the TFS-Git repository (including Microsofts new git tooling inside VS - but that's still a work in progress).  Then you can do any git workflow you like, such as git-flow.

More info on Git in TFS here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx

Alternatively, if you stick with TFSVC, you need to educate yourself on branching workflows that are supported (TFVC is more restrictive than Git on what workflows are supported, but you can definitely achieve something like git-flow).  The best source of knowledge for this is probably the ALM Rangers Branching Guidance: http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

Note: The tool you linked only helps with creating the initial branch structure.  The day to day work is done using the out of the box source control and branch/merge tooling in Visual Studio.

Comment: I was actually using a free visualstudio.com account to play with the git hosting. This works fine. I just feel the Visual STudio tools for git experience is a bit complex, compared to other software (SourceTree or even Githob for Windows). The branching guidance you mentioned is explaining well the philosophy of classic branching guide. But I don't remember this covers to tooling, nor how to "guide" (restrict is a better word) developer in their branching and merging job.

Comment: With Git in TFS you are not limited to the VS Tools.  You can use SourceTree, or any command-line based Git tools, or whatever other windows clients are out there.  Not sure how you guide/restrict developers in the git world, but in TFS the only options I can think of are using security to restrict which branches they have permissions to merge to.  If you can explain more how you want to guide/restrict I may be able to give a better suggestions.

Comment: Also TFS only really supports merging to a direct parent or child branch (you can get around this, but TFS definitely does it's best to discourage that).  This is part of the restrictions I mentioned that TFVC has limiting the supported workflows.

Comment: By restricting, I mean avoiding misuse of the dev workflow. For example, I don't want a "Feature" branch to be merged directly in a "Hotfix" branch. It's not a matter of permission (all members of team are equals... this is a small team of 3-5 people). As I said, the team is immature and branching is new for us. I want to guide developer at maximum in the right way. And I also fear that moving to GIT, even hosted on TFS 2013, will forbid me to later benefits the automated build and/or unit testing.

Comment: Anyways, this answer my question. TFS Branching Tool is ... hum.... quite useless. thx